# Can't access .xlsx file in a subdirectory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Here's my problem:

- I have wordpress installed in the root folder
- I created a folder named `demo`, also in the root folder
- Now, this setup works, I can access php files inside the `demo` folder just fine (e.g. `http://example.com/demo/test.php`) as well as text files
- The problem is when I try to access `.xlsx files inside the`demo` folder the 404 page shows up

I'm not really sure if the problem is the `.htaccess` but here it is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best secure way to put files in wp-content to be able to easily access them